# Problema ao tentar fazer dois insert C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

estou tendo um problema na hora de fazer dois insert usando um valor armazenado em uma variável do sql, o erro que retorna é o seguinte:

```
(fatal error encountered during command execution.
Parameter '@idCo' must be defined)
```

Código:

```
     public void Cadastrar()
        {

            DateTime data = DateTime.Now.Date;


            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "START TRANSACTION;" +
  "INSERT INTO Contato(email, tel_celular, tel_comercial, tel_residencial)" +
  $"VALUES(@email,@tel_celular,@tel_comercial,@tel_residencial);" +
                "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @idCo;" +
                "INSERT INTO Endereco(bairro, cep, cidade, endereco, municipio, zona_secao)" +
  "VALUES(@bairro,@cep,@cidade,@endereco,@municipio,@zona);" +
                "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @idEn;" +
                "INSERT INTO Pessoa(cpf, nome, data_nascimento, nome_pai, nome_mae, sexo, profissao, " +
                "estado_civil, naturalidade, nacionalidade, grau_instrucao, rg, orgao_expeditor, data_emisao," +
                " titulo_de_eleitor, cins, data_cadastro, id_usuario, id_contato, id_endereco)" +
 " VALUES(@cpf,@nome,@nascimento,@pai,@mae,@sexo,@profissao,@estado_civil,@naturalidade, @nacionalidade,@instrucao," +
 $" @rg,@orgao_expeditor,@data_emissao,@titulo_eleitor,@cins,@data_atual, 'henderson', @idCo,@idEn);" +
 " COMMIT; ";



                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel_celular", TelCelular);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel_comercial", TelComercial);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel_residencial", TelResidencial);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bairro", Bairro);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cep", CEP);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cidade", Cidade);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", Enderecocasa);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@municipio", Municipio);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zona", ZonaSecao);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", CPF);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", Nome);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nascimento", DataNascimento);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pai", NomePai);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mae", NomeMae);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", Sexo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profissao", Profissao);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado_civil", EstadoCivil);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naturalidade", Naturalidade);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nacionalidade", Nacionalidade);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instrucao", GrauInstrucao);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", RG);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orgao_expeditor", OrgaoExpeditor);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_emissao", DataEmisao);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo_eleitor", TituloEleitor);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cins", CINS);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_atual", data.ToString("d"));


                cmd.Connection = conexao.conectar();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Cadastro Salvo");
            }
            catch (MySqlException mye)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro, Cadastro nao realizado : " + mye.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.desconectar();
            }
```

Pelo que parece, C# entende que por ter um @ na frente, seria mais um parâmetro para ser passado com cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(), mas como eu não passo nenhum, ele me retornar um erro.

Se minha analise tiver certa, como que eu faço para contornar isso?

Comment: Pelo visto está faltando informar o campo `idCo` dentro de seu insert, verifique as tabelas no banco de dados que você está utilizando. Se for uma `PK` poderá defini-la como `auto-increment` assim não é necessário informar no `insert`.

Comment: obrigado pelo comentário amigo, no caso a tabela esta certinha, eu usei esse comando no phpmyadmin e funcionou de boa, e eu especifiquei no insert o nome da coluna que iria receber o valor do @idCo.
 No caso as 3 tabelas tem chave primaria com auto incremento, teria como me da um exemplo de como ficaria do jeito que você esta me falando?!

Comment: No caso você tem o parâmetro informando `@idCo` e não está informando o valor dele no seu `AddWithValue`, teria que ser algo do tipo `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCo", proximoValor);`. Você terá o mesmo problema com `@idEn`